# Adding Different Columns to ListView based on DataType [WPF, XAML]

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I have this method that is used to set the columns and data in the listview based on a string. I'm not sure how to add the columns I need programactically. I need to use different data types though.

```
private void populateLeaderBoardList()
    {
        string btnContent = (string)btn_exportLeaderBoard.Content;
        if (btnContent.Contains("Totals"))
        {
            // Using data type Player
            // Set Columns (leaderBoardPosition (#++ each row), playerTeamName, playerPoints)
        }
        else if (btnContent.Contains("Players"))
        {
            // Using data type Player
            // Set Columns (leaderBoardPosition (#++ each row), playerTeamName, playerPoints)
        }
        else if (btnContent.Contains("Drivers"))
        {
            // Using data type DriverPoints
            // Set Columns (leaderBoardPosition (#++ each row), driverCarNumber, driverName, driverPoints)
        }
    }
```

How would I go about defining this?

I'm new to WPF and XAML, and this is NOT for work or school.

Comment: Why you are not using a `DataGrid` ? And are you aware of 'DataTemplate' ?

Comment: Read about template selector.

Comment: To be clear, do all the different datatypes need to be shown in the same listbox at the same time? What is the goal? For sometimes the developer may be trying to solve a problem which is better done in an alternate way.